Confused on double sum of non absolute convergent
I'm confuse and can't find my mistakes on the homework. The question asked to prove that
$$H(z):=\sum_{m\in\mathbb Z}\sum_{\substack{n\in\mathbb Z\\ (m,n)\not=(0,0),(1,0)}}\dfrac{1}{(m-1+nz)(m+nz)}=2-\dfrac{2\pi i}{z}.$$
My attempt failed and proved that it is $2$. I use the identity
$$\sum_{n\geqslant 1} \left(\dfrac{1}{z+n}+\dfrac{1}{z-n}\right)=\pi\cot(\pi z)-\dfrac{1}{z}$$
regularly through the arguments. First, I write $H(z)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb Z} H_m(z)$ and determine that
$$H_m(z)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{z}\left(\pi\cot\pi\left(\dfrac{m-1}{z}\right)-\pi\cot\pi\left(\dfrac{m}{z}\right)\right), & \text{if $m\not=0,1$}\\
            1-\dfrac{1}{z}\pi\cot\left(\dfrac{\pi}{z}\right), & \text{if $m=0,1$}
\end{cases}.$$
To determin $H_m(z)$, I fix each $m$ (and $z$ is firstly fixed) so the inner sum is absolute convergent in variable $n$ and so can be rearranged. For $m\not=0,1$, I have
$$\begin{align*} H_m(z) &=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\dfrac{1}{(m-1+nz)(m+nz)}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{m(m-1)}+\sum_{n\geqslant 1} \left(\dfrac{1}{(m-1+nz)(m+nz)}+\dfrac{1}{(-(m-1)+nz)(-m+nz)}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{m(m-1)}+\dfrac{1}{z}\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\frac{m-1}{z}+n}+\dfrac{1}{\frac{m-1}{z}-n}\right)-\dfrac{1}{z}\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\frac{m}{z}+n}+\dfrac{1}{\frac{m}{z}-n}\right)
\\ &=\dfrac{1}{m(m-1)}+\dfrac{1}{z}\left(\pi\cot\pi\left(\dfrac{m-1}{z}\right)-\dfrac{z}{m-1}\right)-\dfrac{1}{z}\left(\pi\cot\pi\left(\dfrac{m}{z}\right)-\dfrac{z}{m}\right),
\end{align*}$$
which is as stated in the first case. Now, for $m=0$,
$$\begin{align*}
H_0(z) &=\sum_{n\not=0} \dfrac{1}{nz(nz-1)}=\sum_{n\geqslant 1} \left(\dfrac{1}{nz(nz-1)}+\dfrac{1}{nz(nz+1)}\right)\\
&= \dfrac{1}{z}\sum_{n\geqslant 1} \left(\dfrac{1}{-\frac{1}{z}+n}+\dfrac{1}{-\frac{1}{z}-n}\right)=\dfrac{1}{z}\left(\pi\cot\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{z}\right)+z\right)=1-\dfrac{1}{z}\pi\cot\left(\dfrac{\pi}{z}\right),
\end{align*}
$$
which is part of the second case, and similarly, I have the same term for $m=1$. However, when sum back to
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{m\in \mathbb Z} H_m(z) &=\sum_{m>1} +\sum_{m<0} +\sum_{m=0,1}\\
&= \dfrac{1}{z}\left(\pi\cot\dfrac{\pi}{z}-\pi\cot\dfrac{2\pi}{z}+\pi\cot\dfrac{2\pi}{z}-\pi\cot\dfrac{3\pi}{z}+\pi\cot\dfrac{3\pi}{z}-\pi\cot\dfrac{4\pi}{z}\pm\cdots\right)\\
&+\dfrac{1}{z}\left(\pi\cot\dfrac{-2\pi}{z}-\pi\cot\dfrac{-\pi}{z}+\pi\cot\dfrac{-3\pi}{z}-\pi\cot\dfrac{-2\pi}{z}+\pi\cot\dfrac{-4\pi}{z}-\pi\cot\dfrac{-3\pi}{z}\pm\cdots\right)\\
&+ 2-\dfrac{2}{z}\pi\cot\left(\dfrac{\pi}{z}\right)=2,
\end{align*}
$$
which is undesirable. Could you help me where the mistakes are?

Let $H_m(z)$ denote the inner sum:
$$ H_m(z) = \sum_{\substack{n \in \mathbb{Z} \\ (m,n) \neq (0, 0), (1, 0)}} \frac{1}{(m-1+nz)(m+nz)} $$
Then for $m \neq 0, 1$,
\begin{align*}
H_m(z)
&= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{(m-1+nz)(m+nz)} \\
&= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \biggl[ \frac{1}{m-1+nz} - \frac{1}{m+nz} \biggr] \\
&= \frac{\pi}{z} \cot\Bigl(\frac{\pi (m-1)}{z}\Bigr) - \frac{\pi}{z} \cot\Bigl(\frac{\pi m}{z}\Bigr).
\end{align*}
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
H_0(z)
= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}} \frac{1}{(-1+nz)(nz)}
\stackrel{(n \mapsto -n)}= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}} \frac{1}{(1+nz)(nz)}
= H_1(z)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
H_1(z)
&= \frac{1}{z} \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}} \left[ \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+z^{-1}} \right] \\
&= 1 - \frac{\pi}{z} \cot\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{z}\Bigr).
\end{align*}
Now we plug these back into the original double sum $H(z)$. In doing so, we first consider the partial sums of $H_m(z)$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=-M+1}^{N} H_m(z)
&= \sum_{m=-M+1}^{-1} \left[ \frac{\pi}{z} \cot\Bigl(\frac{\pi (m-1)}{z}\Bigr) - \frac{\pi}{z} \cot\Bigl(\frac{\pi m}{z}\Bigr) \right]
+ 2\left( 1 - \frac{\pi}{z} \cot\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{z}\Bigr) \right) \\
&\quad + \sum_{m=2}^{N} \left[ \frac{\pi}{z} \cot\Bigl(\frac{\pi (m-1)}{z}\Bigr) - \frac{\pi}{z} \cot\Bigl(\frac{\pi m}{z}\Bigr) \right] \\
&= 2 - \frac{\pi}{z} \cot\Bigl(\frac{\pi M}{z}\Bigr) - \frac{\pi}{z} \cot\Bigl(\frac{\pi N}{z}\Bigr).
\end{align*}
Now assume that $\operatorname{Im}(z) > 0$, and write $z^{-1} = \sigma - i\xi$ for $\sigma, \xi \in \mathbb{R}$. It is clear that $\xi > 0$. So,
$$ \cot\Bigl(\frac{\pi N}{z}\Bigr)
= \frac{\sin(2 \pi N\sigma)}{\cosh (2 \pi N\xi) - \cos (2\pi N\sigma)} + i \frac{\sinh (2 \pi N\xi)}{\cosh (2 \pi N\xi) - \cos (2\pi N\sigma)}. $$
Letting $N \to \infty$, this converges to $i$. The same is true if $N$ is replaced by $M$. Therefore,
$$ \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}} H_m(z)
= \lim_{M,N \to \infty} \sum_{m=-M+1}^{N} H_m(z)
= 2 - \frac{2\pi i}{z}. $$

Good job. I thought no one is interested in this. I had found the way I mistook the sum.
